# Unable to find bundled version Windows (Andriod Studio 2022.1)

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

I tried all day to figure this out but still can't seem to find bundled Java. What am I missing here?

So I've tried to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio 2022.1 multiple times. Deleted all the Javas and re-downloaded as well.

[Picture of Flutter Doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yva3N.png)

[Current Java Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgZwm.png)

[Current User variables for Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AtWU.png)

[Environment Varibles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LS3VF.png)

[Path for System variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSan1.png)

I've deleted, re-downloaded all Java & Android Studios. Still missing bundled Java.

Comment: One thing I'm sure of, Android does not support Java 19. Last time I checked, Java 8.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot say this is the best correct answer, but if you noticed, the `Android Studio\jre\bin` directory is empty. The bundled java is located in `Android Studio\jbr\bin` instead.

My ***quick-n-dirty*** fix was that I just copied the files in `\jbr\*` to `\jre\` and now `flutter doctor` doesn't complain.